# How to list all existing keyboard shortcuts in Cinnamon?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, cinnamon

Cinnamon help (F1) comes with a list of most commonly used keyboard shortcuts, but it's not complete. It's also possible to add customization, so you can't really make a fixed list of keyboard shortcuts. But there should be a way to list all existing shortcuts, all default ones plus the custom ones.

You can kind of get the existing shortcuts, but opening the keyboard customization dialog and going through the list of all possible actions. In theory you will discover existing shortcuts, but the list of actions is much longer than default shortcuts, so you'll spend most of the time finding out that such-and-such action has no assigned shortcut.

So, is there a way to list the currently configured keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **dconf-editor** to view the keyboard bindings. Look under `/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings`. You will see subdirectories (*wm* and *media-keys*) that contain all of the configured (and unconfigured) keyboard mappings.